# Modify datetime using awk/sed

Tags: awk, sed

I have a log file which contains series of timestamps. I need to modify it in a certain way.

Log file:

```
['2015-11-04', '13:47:37:167']
['2015-11-04', '13:47:47:164']
['2015-11-04', '13:47:57:164']
['2015-11-04', '13:48:07:164']
['2015-11-04', '13:48:17:164']
['2015-11-04', '13:48:27:166']
['2015-11-04', '13:48:37:164']
['2015-11-04', '13:48:47:164']
['2015-11-04', '13:48:57:167']
['2015-11-04', '13:49:07:164']
['2015-11-04', '13:49:17:166']
['2015-11-04', '13:49:27:164']
['2015-11-04', '13:49:37:164']
['2015-11-04', '13:49:47:165']
['2015-11-04', '13:49:57:164']
```

This is the sample output I'm expecting in each line    `2015-11-04T13:49:57.164Z`

How can I achieve this?

Thakns.

Comment: Check `man date`, using `date -d"..."` and then `+"%..."` you can do magic

Comment: @fedorqui - the `-d` option is Linux-specific. Also important to mention the `-f` option in BSD/OSX's `date` command.

Comment: Araz, are you interested in converting times based on a particular time zone, or just massaging the input as text?

Comment: @ghoti no a specific time zone. just as string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sed expression is not very readable because of the need to escape the quotes, so maybe use double quotes:

```
sed 's/\['\''\(.*\)'\'', '\''\(.*\):\(.*\)'\''\]/\1T\2.\3Z/'
sed "s/\['\(.*\)', '\(.*\):\(.*\)'\]/\1T\2.\3Z/"
```

or maybe even `-r` if your sed supports it:

```
sed -r "s/\['(.*)', '(.*):(.*)'\]/\1T\2.\3Z/"
```

Answer (score 2):

Extracting substrings, and creating the new timestamp:

```
perl -pe 'substr($_,0,30) = sprintf "%sT%s.%sZ", substr($_,2,10), substr($_,16,8), substr($_,25,3)' file
```

Answer (score 2):

Or

```
 awk '{
  gsub(/[\\]\\[\\['"'"']/, "", $0)
  sub(/,/, "\\t", $0) 
  sub(/:/,"x",$2); sub(/:/,"x",$2); sub(/:/,".",$2)
  gsub(/x/,":",$2)
  print $1 "T" $2 "Z"}' logFile
```

**output**

```
2015-11-04T13:47:37.167Z
2015-11-04T13:47:47.164Z
2015-11-04T13:47:57.164Z
2015-11-04T13:48:07.164Z
2015-11-04T13:48:17.164Z
2015-11-04T13:48:27.166Z
2015-11-04T13:48:37.164Z
2015-11-04T13:48:47.164Z
2015-11-04T13:48:57.167Z
2015-11-04T13:49:07.164Z
2015-11-04T13:49:17.166Z
2015-11-04T13:49:27.164Z
2015-11-04T13:49:37.164Z
2015-11-04T13:49:47.165Z
2015-11-04T13:49:57.164Z
```

A little clunky, but for some eyes, it may be a little easier to follow what is happening.

IHTH

Answer (score 2):

If you're just processing text, the following might be sufficient.

```
awk -F'[^0-9:-]+' '{print $2"T"$3"Z"}'
```

Of course, this doesn't convert the last colon to a dot.  For that, you might be able to brute-force it, trusting that your time format won't change:

```
awk -F'[^0-9:-]+' '{printf("%sT%s.%sZ\n",$2,substr($3,1,8),substr($3,10))}'
```

Or perhaps even:

```
awk -F'[^0-9-]+' '{printf("%sT%s:%s:%s.%sZ\n",$2,$3,$4,$5,$6)}'
```

Answer (score 2):

collectively using unix toolset might be better than a single one.

```
tr -d "'[]," <log | tr ' ' 'T' | sed -r 's/:([0-9]{3})$/.\1Z/'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's@[^0-9]*\([0-9\-]*\)[^0-9]*\([0-9:]*\).*@\1T\2Z@;s/:/./3' file
```